# Set attribute on dynamically created Custom component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component belonging to a custom library:

```
<my-icon>
```

In order to have the icon, I should set the property `[name]` of this component. Something like this:

```
<my-icon [name]='warning'></my-icon>
```

I am dinamically creating these icons with TypeScript:

```
if (myCondition) {
    let icon = <HTMLElement>document.createElement('my-icon');
}
```

How should I set the property `[name]` in my variable `icon` in order to have the same result than above? 
I've tried `icon.setAttribute('name','warning')` but it doesn't work (that sets the HTML attribute `name`, and not the input `name` of the underlying Angular component.

Comment: you should use `Renderer2` to manipulate DOM. It has also methods to `setProperty`, `setAttribute` etc

Answer (score 1):

`document.create` does not create Angular component but only DOM element. If you want to dynamically create Angular component you should inject `ComponentFactoryResolver` service

```
constructor(private componentResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
```

which can be later used like this:

```
// create factory for icon component
const factory = this.componentResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyIconComponent);

// create icon component and append it next to anchor element
const icon = this.anchor.createComponent(factory);

// assign some value to component input
icon.instance.name = 'icon name';
```

Anchor element can be obtained using `ViewChild` e.g. if your component template looks like this:

```
`<div #iconsHere></div>`
```

you'll have to add the following annotation:

```
  @ViewChild('iconsHere', {read: ViewContainerRef}) anchor: ViewContainerRef;
```

Please note that dynamically created components have to be declared as entry components in your module.

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  entryComponents: [ MyIconComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Demo: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jukjib